# Where do i put the curl request while building a getstarted button for messenger bot using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, curl

i'm really a beginner in node js and bot building , do i place the facebook curl request code below :

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"`

In my package.json file or my index.js file ?

Any help ? please tell me more about curl request in node js if possible , how it works and so on

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i just needed to run it in Terminal !